# How can I select several XML elements using XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Assuming the following XML :

```
<response>
<header>
<resultCode>0000</resultCode>
<resultMsg>OK</resultMsg>
</header>
<body>
<items>
 <item>
  <addr1>America</addr1>
  <addr2>(Atlanta)</addr2>
 </item>
 <item>
  <addr1>Canada</addr1>
  <addr2>(Toronto)</addr2>
 </item>
 <item>
  <addr1>France</addr1>
  <addr2>(Paris)</addr2>
 </item>
 </items>
</body>
</response>
```

I wanted to select several XML elements using XPath. 
So, I wrote the JAVA code below.

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(urlBuilder.toString());

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

NodeList items = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//item", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET );
NodeList addrAll= (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//item/addr1 | //item/addr2", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println("length:"+addrAll.getLength());      
for(int tmp=0; tmp<addrAll.getLength();tmp++){
    System.out.println(addrAll.item(tmp).getTextContent());
}
```

The result is:

```
    length:6
    America
    (Atlanta)
    Canada
    (Toronto)
    France
    (Paris)
```

But, this is not what I wanted.
My expected output:

```
length:3    
America (Atlanta)
Canada (Toronto)
France (Paris)
```

I hope you understand my question.
How can I edit my code to do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question! you are asking it wrong or explaining it wrong! but as far as I understood, you want them in 1 line while you are using a println therefore you get all of them printed out in each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how xpath works; it retrieves the information it designates, but won't concatenate several data points.

To do that, you'll have either use xslt, or you can create two xpaths, one for each of the addrX parts, and then have the Java client code combine them.

How you need to update your Java code depends on several things, like if each `item` will always contain both an `addr1` and `addr2`, for example.

If you can rely on that, you can do this:

```
System.out.println("length:"+addrAll.getLength());      
for(int tmp=0; tmp<addrAll.getLength();tmp+=2){
    String country = addrAll.item(tmp).getTextContent();
    String city = addrAll.item(tmp+1).getTextContent();
    System.out.printf("%s %s\n", country, city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 has a limited set of data types available: string, boolean, number, and node-set. Your desired answer is a sequence of three strings, which don't correspond to existing nodes, and there's no such thing in XPath 1.0 as a sequence of three strings.

If you're in the Java world, there's really no reason to restrict yourself to XPath 1.0. XPath 2.0 extends the type system to allow a sequence of strings, so you can get your answer with an expression such as `//item/concat(addr1, ' ', addr2)` or `//item/string-join(*, ' ')`.

XPath 2.0 has been around for more than ten years - time to move forward! You might also consider using a more modern tree model than DOM: JDOM2 and XOM are vastly easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> items = wd.findElements(By.xpath("//items/item"));
System.out.println("length: " + items.size());
items.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getText()));
```

Output:

```
length: 3 
America (Atlanta) 
Canada (Toronto) 
France (Paris)
```

You could put into the List or Map.